# Changing x-axis without changing index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame 'tso':

```
tso=DataFrame(temp,index=datet)
#tso['Month']=tso.index.month
tso['Year']=tso.index.year
tso['Day']=tso.index.dayofyear
ax=tso.groupby(['Day','Year']).mean().unstack().plot()
```

here is the picture:
[image]

I want to change x-axis as 'month' instead of 'Day' .And when I zoom-in/out the figure,the x-axis can corresponding changes.

Comment: Is there an issue here that the 1st march is on a different dayofyear on leap years? Saying that, I suspect you can recklessly do this using [`tick_params`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params)...

Comment: thank you~~I create a new DataFrame with tso1.values and a Datetime index which generates through 'Day'(1-366). tso1=tso.groupby(['Day','Year']).mean().unstack()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new DataFrame:

```
tso1=tso.groupby(['Day','Year']).mean().unstack()
#################creat the datetime index#################################
date=[]
for i in range(len(tso1.index)-1):
    date.append(parser.parse(num2date(tso1.index[i]).replace(year=2000).isoformat(" ")))
date.append(parser.parse(num2date(tso1.index[len(tso1.index)-2]).replace(year=2000).isoformat(" ")))
######################################################################################################
ax = pandas.DataFrame(tso1.values,index=date).plot()
```